# how to use htaccess to change my image path?

Tags: .htaccess

what i try to do is hide my image path.
but it does't working.
from localhost/resource/image/test/m2.jpg to localhost/img/test/m2.jpg

RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/$ resource/image/$1

am i nid a full path?
any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file  in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^img/(.+)$ resource/image/$1 [NC,L]
```